# How to modify default parameters in the Algorithmic Environment module using LyX?

Tags: floats, lyx, algorithms, preamble

I'm using LyX together with the Springer Journal LaTeX template to write a document. I'm also using the Algorithmic Environment module to create an algorithm layout within my document. The problem is that every time I compile the file, I get the following error:

```
No counter 'chapter' defined.
```

I found the line that is causing the problem and is this:

```
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
```

Basically, the Springer template is not divided in chapters, but in sections, so I decided to use the LyX preamble and correct this by writing:

```
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}[section]
```

But it seems it is not working because I keep getting the same error on the same line, like if I hadn't written anything in the preamble. Does anybody know how can I solve this?

I'm using LyX 2.1.2 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble, re-enter the Algorithm float as a Local Layout:

```
Format 49
Float
    Type                  algorithm
    GuiName               Algorithm
    Placement             tbp
    Extension             loa
    NumberWithin          none
    Style                 ruled
    ListName              "List of Algorithms"
    IsPredefined          false
    UsesFloatPkg          true
    RefPrefix             alg
End
```

This respecifies that an Algorithm should not have any "NumberWithin" attribute, and therefore will be defined using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) (`UsesFloatPkg` is set to `true`) *without* the `[chapter]` appendage.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Werner! It worked perfectly fine. I really appreciate your help!